# Get the object array indexOf duplicate element in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, excel, duplicates

I have a big problem for me. I guess stackoverflow members can help me.. I have an Excel file in my local. And than I want to read this Excel and if Excel rows have a duplicate data than I write to console.

For example clearly;

This is my Excel file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3fd1.png)

And than my reading excel row code:

```
workbook.xlsx.readFile('excelvalidation.xlsx').then(function() {
    var rowValues = {};
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
    var columnCount = worksheet.columnCount;

    worksheet.eachRow(function(row, rowNumber) {
        if(rowNumber > 2) {
            var dizi = [];
            row.eachCell(function(cell, colNumber){
            dizi.push(cell.value);
        });

        rowValues[rowNumber-3] = dizi;
    }
});

for(var i = 0 ; i < Object.keys(rowValues).length ; i++) {
    console.log(" " + rowValues[i]);
}
```

`rowValues` is object what have a all row. it means 1. row is `rowValues` first element and 2. row is rowValues second element vs...

So in Excel file row 5. and 11. duplicate and I want to write console for message "5 and 11 row is duplicate" what I want. How can I do it? Thanks for helps..

Comment: So what you want is to compare two or more array of cells ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate an md5 hash for each item in rowValues, by concatenating the values in the array into a single string, then using md5 function.
This hash can then be used as the index to the rows which had these values (the values which resulted in that md5 hash).

Here's a sample implementation that can detect multiple occurrences (more than 2 duplicate rows):

```
var rowValues = [
  ['E', '10-15', 'ankara'],
  ['E', '10-15', 'antalya'],
  ['E', '20-25', 'ankara'],
  ['E', '20-25', 'antalya'],
  ['K', '10-15', 'ankara'],
  ['K', '10-15', 'antalya'],
  ['K', '20-25', 'ankara'],
  ['K', '20-25', 'antalya'],
  ['E', '20-25', 'ankara'],
  ['K', '10-15', 'antalya'],
  ['E', '20-25', 'ankara'],
];

var hashes = {};

rowValues.forEach(function(row, idx){
  var hash = md5(row.join('~~~'));
  if (hash in hashes) {
    hashes[hash].push(idx);
  } else {
    hashes[hash] = [idx];
  }
})

Object.keys(hashes).forEach(function(key, idx) {
  var msg = '';
  if (hashes[key].length > 1) {
    msg = 'Rows ' + hashes[key].join(' and ') + ' are duplicate\n';
    console.log(msg);
  }
});
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/b5nqbavq/2/